# Error in order function

Tags: r

I am having trouble with the order function in R.  Starting from a fresh session, I get

```
iris[98:99,3]
[1] 4.3 3.0
order(iris[98:99,3])
[1] 2 1
order(iris[,3])[98:99]
[1] 127 139
```

The first order statement says that if I sort only the two elements in question, order correctly says that 4.3 comes after 3.0.  OK.  But when I sort the entire column and just ask about the order of elements 98 an 99, order seems to think that the 3.0 comes after 4.3. Am I misinterpreting something here or is this an error?

In case it matters

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a result of switching of the bracket

```
order(iris[,3][98:99])
#[1] 2 1
```

---

In the OP's post,

```
order(iris[,3])
```

gives the `order` of the entire column and then we are selecting the 98th and 99th observation

```
order(iris[,3])[98:99]
#[1] 127 139
```

We need to look at the `rank` here

```
order(order(iris[,3]))[98:99]
#[1] 75 51
```

Comment: Yes. But doesn't this mean that the 98th element comes before the 99th in a sorted list - which would be wrong?

Comment: @GSW you may need to look at the `rank` or `order(order`.

Comment: @G5W I think you have some problem with what the `order` outputs

Comment: You are right.  this was just a silly mistake.

Answer (score 3):

It's working correctly, but you are referencing the wrong numbers in your mind. The result of `order` is the *indexes* of the original vector, meaning

```
order(iris[,3])[98:99]
127 139
```

says that if you arrange the iris[, 3] elements from small to large and look at the 98th and 99th one, you'll get number 127 and 139 from the original vector (which are both 4.8).